# Instantiate an object in function parameter

Tags: javascript

how do I pass an instantiated object's properties as a parameter in a JavaScript function.
I want to do this so that I am forced to always use the same properties of the object.

How do I do this?

```
//object
var house = {
    bed:"",
    chair:"",
    tv,""

};

//function
var doThis = function(OBJ){

    //pass this OBJ to something
    alert(OBJ.bed);
    alert(OBJ.chair);
    alert(OBJ.tv);


};


//call function
doThis({new house.bed = "a", new house.chair="c", new house.tv = "f"});

doThis({new house.bed = "dd", new house.chair="gg", new house.tv = "jjjh"});

doThis({new house.bed = "ff", new house.chair="hh", new house.tv = "hhh"});

doThis({new house.bed = "gg", new house.chair="jjj", new house.tv = "hh"});
```

Comment: I don't get what you want. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: this hard to write.. um I want to instantiate the new object and set it properties in the function parameter   .. doThis({new house ={ bed:"a", chair:"c", tv : "f"});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty far away from javascript, but you can do this:

```
function House(bed, chair, tv) {
    this.bed = bed;
    this.chair = chair;
    this.tv = tv;
}
doThis(new House("a", "c", "f"));
doThis(new House("dd", "gg", "asd"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't quite understand the problem, but your code contains syntax errors, the invocation of function should be like this:

```
doThis({bed: "a", chair: "c", house: "f"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Esailija said except that doThis is not defined, so use something like this:

```
function House(bed,chair,tv){
    var obj = {};
    obj.bed = (bed) ? bed : "";
    obj.chair = (chair) ? chair : "";
    obj.tv = (tv) ? tv : "";
    return obj;
  }

  var myHouse = new House('water bed');
```

Comment: and you can put 0 - 3 parameters in for the new house object, if a parameter is missing it will assign that property to an empty string

Comment: and you can also prototype the house object, which can help make it act more like a real object oriented language